# Why does scala.util.Failure have a type parameter?

Tags: scala, types

`scala.util.Failure` is declared like this:

```
final case class Failure[+T](exception: Throwable) extends Try[T]`
```

It takes a type parameter `T` which looks completely unnecessary, given how `Failure` could just as easily be declared as a sub-type of `Try[Nothing]`:

```
final case class Failure(exception: Throwable) extends Try[Nothing]`
```

in the same way that `None` is declared like:

```
object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

Indeed, the extra type parameter becames a pain point elsewhere. Here is `Future.zip`:

```
def zip[U](that: Future[U]): Future[(T, U)] = {
  implicit val ec = internalExecutor
  val p = Promise[(T, U)]()
  onComplete {
    case f: Failure[_] => p complete f.asInstanceOf[Failure[(T, U)]]
    case Success(s) => that onComplete { c => p.complete(c map { s2 => (s, s2) }) }
  }
  p.future
}
```

The line:

```
    case f: Failure[_] => p complete f.asInstanceOf[Failure[(T, U)]]
```

could be simplified to:

```
    case f: Failure => p complete f
```

If failure had been declared a sub-type of `Try[Nothing]`.

I feel like I must be missing something here. The only reason I could come up with for the type parameter is to declare that an expression represents the failure to compute a particular type, and to make explicit it is a failure unlike just using `Try[T]`, but I can't imagine a situation where this would really be needed.

Comment: fundamentally the same question, but about `Either`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656786/why-do-left-and-right-have-two-type-parameters

Answer (score 4):

The `T` in `Failure[+T]` comes in handy when trying to recover from the failure: `recover[U >: T](rescueException: PartialFunction[Throwable, U]): Try[U]`

Comment: Not really, this would still work with `Failure` sub-typing `Try[Nothing]`, in the same way `getOrElse` works for `None`.

Comment: There are no sub-types of `Nothing` and by extension no subtypes of any type that is covariant in a type parameter given as `Nothing`. By definition `Nothing` is the subtype of all types.

Comment: @RandallSchulz: That is incorrect. `Option[+A]` is covariant in its parameter, and Option[Nothing] has a sub-type, `None`.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner: Of course... The subtype relation is reflexive. Only if it were irreflexive would what I said be true.