# why does Failure[T] have a type parameter when Try is the same as Either[Throwable,T]?

Tags: scala, error-handling, future, either

I am reading [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) :

> The Try[T] is similar to Option[T] or Either[T, S], in that it is a
>   monad potentially holding a value of some type. However, it has been
>   specifically designed to either hold a value or some throwable object.
>   Where an Option[T] could either be a value (i.e. Some[T]) or no value
>   at all (i.e. None), Try[T] is a Success[T] when it holds a value and
>   otherwise Failure[T], which holds an exception. Failure[T] holds more
>   information than just a plain None by saying why the value is not
>   there. **In the same time, you can think of Try[T] as a special version
>   of Either[Throwable, T], specialized for the case when the left value
>   is a Throwable.**

So if `Try[T]` is like `Either[Throwable, T]` then what point does it make to make `Failure[T]` have a type parameter `T` ? This is really confusing. Can someone unconfuse me ?

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904250/why-does-scala-util-failure-have-a-type-parameter?