# Why do `Left` and `Right` have two type parameters?

Tags: scala, either

I understand it would be difficult to change now without breaking existing code, but I'm wondering why it was done that way in the first place.

Why not just:

```
sealed trait Either[+A, +B]
case class Left[A](x: A) extends Either[A, Nothing]
case class Right[B](x: B) extends Either[Nothing, B]
```

Is there some drawback here that I'm failing to see...?

Comment: Note that somebody asked the same question about `Try` here but never got a satisfactory answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904250/why-does-scala-util-failure-have-a-type-parameter

Comment: Related [discussion](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/change-either-subclasses-type-parameters/1918/2) on the contributors channel. It is not clear why the original design was like that, but it seems the change was not made because it could break code _(which is not that bad)_ but would also break cross-compilation _(really bad!)_ of course that could have been solved using something like `scala-collection-compat` library, but it seems that wasn't a thing back then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure how relevant this answer really is to Scala, but it certainly is in Haskell which is evidently where Scala's `Either` was borrowed from and so that's probably the best historical reason for why Scala did it this way.

`Either` is the canonical [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct), i.e. for any types `A` and `B` you have

- The type `EitherA,B ≈ A ⊕ B`
- Two coprojections `LeftA,B : A -> A⊕B` and `RightA,B : B -> A⊕B`
- such that for any type `Y` and any functions `fA : A -> Y` and `fB : B -> Y`, there exists exactly one function `f : A⊕B -> Y` with the property that `fA = f ∘ LeftA,B` and `fB = f ∘ RightA,B`.

To formulate this mathematically, it is quite helpful to have the information which particular `Left` you're working with explicit, because else the domains of the morphisms would be all unclear. In Scala this may be unnecessary because of implicit covariant conversion, but not in maths and not in Haskell.

In Haskell it isn't really an issue at all, because type inference will automatically do what's needed:

```hs
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/haskell-stack-ghci/2a3bbd58/ghci-script
Prelude> let right2 = Right 2
Prelude> let left42 = Left 42.0
Prelude> (+) <$> right2 <*> left42
Left 42.0
```

Unlike, apparently, in Scala, Haskell just leaves the unspecified second argument of `left42` as a *type variable* (unless the monomorphism restriction is enabled), so you can later use it in any context requiring some `Either Double R` for any type `R`. Of course it's possible to make that explicit too

```
right2 :: Either a Int
right2 = Right 2

left42 :: Either Double a
left42 = Left 42

main :: IO ()
main = print $ (+) <$> right2 <*> left42
```

which surely is possible in Scala just as well.

Comment: This is probably a pretty good answer to the "why" question in the title, given that the original author of `scala.Either` is also the original author of Scalaz.

Answer (score 10):

There's no meaningful drawback that I've found to your scheme.  For the last eight years or so I've used my own variant of `Either` which is exactly as you describe under another name (`Ok[+Y, +N]` with `Yes[+Y]` and `No[+N]` as the alternatives).  (Historical note: I started when `Either` was not right-biased, and wanted something that was; but then I kept using my version because it was more convenient to have only half the types.)

The only case I've ever found where it matters is when you pattern match out one branch and no longer have access to the type information of the other branch.

```scala
def foo[A, B: Typeclass](e: Either[A, B]) =
  implicitly[Typeclass[B]].whatever()

// This works
myEither match {
  case l: Left[L, R]  => foo(l)
  case r: Right[L, R] => foo(r)
}
```

```scala
def bar[N, Y: Typeclass](o: Ok[N, Y]) =
  implicitly[Typeclass[Y]].whatever()

// This doesn't work
myOk match {
  case y: Yes[Y] => bar(y)  // This is fine
  case n: No[N]  => bar(n)  // Y == Nothing!
}
```

However, I never do this.  I could just use `o` to get the right type.  So it doesn't matter!  Everything else is easier (like pattern matching and changing one case and not the other...you don't need `case Left(l) => Left(l)` which rebuilds the `Left` for no reason except to switch the type of the uninhabited branch).

There are other cases (e.g. setting types in advance) that *seem* like they should be important, but in practice are almost impossible to make matter (e.g. because covariance will find the common supertype anyway, so what you set doesn't constrain anything).

So I think the decision was made before there was enough experience with the two ways to do it, and the wrong choice was made.  (It's not a *very* wrong choice; `Either` is still decent.)

Comment: Tysvm for this answer, Rex! Seeing the nuance teased out so explicitly is very satisfying. It also enables a transition to more effective patterns in the future, even if it is too difficult to do it right now. We lived through the transition from the non-Right-biased Either to it being Right-biased. It seems like a similar transition could be enabled to take Either to the same type shape as your Ok solution.

Comment: Thanks, Rex. I could only accept a single answer, but this one is valuable as well.