# Why Scala Infer the Bottom Type when the type parameter is not specified?

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, covariance

I wonder if anyone could explain the inferencing rule in this particular case below, and most importantly it's rational/implication ?

```
case class E[A, B](a: A) // class E
E(2) // E[Int,Nothing] = E(2)
```

Note that I could have wrote `E[Int](2)`. What matter to me is why is the second parameter type inferred to be `Nothing` (i.e. Bottom type) instead of let say `Any` for instance ? Why is that and What's the rational/Implication ?

Just to give some context, this is related to the definition of Either and how it works for Left and Right. Both are defined according to the pattern

```
final case class X[+A, +B](value: A) extends Either[A, B]
```

Where you instantiate it let say as `Right[Int](2)` and the type inferred is `Right[Nothing, Int]` and by extension `Either[Nothing, Int]`

## EDIT1

There is consistency here, but i still can figure out the rational. Below is the same definition with a contra-variant paramete:

```
case class E[A, -B](a: A)// class E
E(2) // E[Int, Any] = E(2)
```

Hence we do have the same thing the other way around when it is contra-variant, and that make the all behavior or inference rule, coherent. However the rational for this i am not sure ....

Why not the opposite rule i.e. infer `Any` when Co-Variant/Invariant and `Nothing` when Contra-Variant ?

## EDIT2

In the light of @slouc Answer, which make good sense, i'm left with still understanding what and why the compiler is doing what it is doing. The example below illustrate my confusion

```
val myleft = Left("Error") // Left[String,Nothing] = Left(Error)
myleft map { (e:Int) => e * 4} // Either[String,Int] = Left(Error)
```

1. First the compiler **fix** the type to something that "for sure work" to reuse the conclusion of @slouc (albeit make more sense in the context of a Function) `Left[String,Nothing]`
2. Next the compile infer `myleft` to be of type  Either[String,Int]

given map definition `def map[B](f: A => B): Either[E, B]`, `(e:Int) => e * 4` can only be supplied if `myleft` is actually `Left[String,Int]` or `Either[String,Int]`

So in other words, my question is, what is the point of fixing the type to `Nothing` if it is to change it later.

Indeed the following does not compile

```
val aleft: Left[String, Nothing] = Left[String, Int]("Error")

type mismatch;
found   : scala.util.Left[String,Int]
required: Left[String,Nothing]
val aleft: Left[String, Nothing] = Left[String, Int]("Error")
```

So why would I infer to a type, that normally would block me to do anything else over variable of that type (*but for sure works in term of inference*), to ultimately change that type, so i can do something with a variable of that inferred type.

## EDIT3

Edit2 is a bit misunderstanding and everything is clarified in @slouc answer and comments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656786/why-do-left-and-right-have-two-type-parameters/64665035#64665035

Comment: thanks for this, i see that it touch the point, but somehow i am not able to connect it well.

Comment: This is way I didn't flag the question as duplicate, but rather posted here as an FYI.

Comment: I really do not understand what you mean with you have to change it latter, or why you say that it will block you to do anything with it? - I also do not understand what would you believe would be better and why. - Finally, I am not sure if you realize than since **Scala** is an eager language we have to infer all the types for each value _(this will somewhat change in **Scala 3** with polymorphic functions)_, whereas in Haskell the types are left open to be inferred when used, note that another reason for that being different in Scala is subtyping _(which AFAIK Haskell doesn't have)_

Comment: Finally, you usually do not have values of type **Nothing**, but rather that is used to ease the combination of multiple values in the correct type.

Comment: I misunderstood things, and explained in my comment in @slouc reply

Comment: @MaatDeamon so does slouc answer answers your question? if so please consider accepting it, if not can you make it clear what is missing?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm coming to it, let me wrap my head around the concept a little, and then i will proceed :) !! Those things have to sink in ;)

Comment: @MaatDeamon got it, sorry if I sounded I like I was giving an order, I just wanting to be sure if the question was answered or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Covariance:
  Given type `F[+A]` and relation `A <: B`, then the following holds: `F[A] <: F[B]`
- Contravariance:
  Given type `F[-A]` and relation `A <: B`, then the following holds: `F[A] >: F[B]`

If the compiler cannot infer the exact type, it will resolve the lowest possible type in case of covariance and highest possible type in case of contravariance.

Why?

This is a very important rule when it comes to variance in subtyping. It can be shown on the example of the following data type from Scala:

```
trait Function1[Input-, Output+]
```

Generally speaking, when a type is placed in the function/method parameters, it means it's in the so-called "contravariant position". If it's used in function/method return values, it's in the so-called "covariant position". If it's in both, then it's invariant.

Now, given the rules from the beginning of this post, we conclude that, given:

```
trait Food
trait Fruit extends Food
trait Apple extends Fruit

def foo(someFunction: Fruit => Fruit) = ???
```

we can supply

```
val f: Food => Apple = ???
foo(f)
```

Function `f` is a valid substitute for `someFunction` because:

- `Food` is a supertype of `Fruit` (contravariance of input)
- `Apple` is a subtype of `Fruit` (covariance of output)

We can explain this in natural language like this:

> "Method `foo` needs a function that can take a `Fruit` and produce a
> `Fruit`. This means `foo` will have some `Fruit` and will need a
> function it can feed it to, and expect some `Fruit` back. If it gets a
> function `Food => Apple`, everything is fine - it can still feed it
> `Fruit` (because the function takes any food), and it can receive
> `Fruit` (apples are fruit, so the contract is respected).

Coming back to your initial dilemma, hopefully this explains why, without any extra information, compiler will resort to lowest possible type for covariant types and highest possible type for contravariant ones. If we want to supply a function to `foo`, there's one that we know surely works: `Any => Nothing`.

[Variance in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

[Variance in Scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html).

[Article about variance in Scala](https://medium.com/javarevisited/variance-in-java-and-scala-63af925d21dc) (full disclosure: I wrote it).

**EDIT:**

I think I know what's confusing you.

When you instantiate a `Left[String, Nothing]`, you're allowed to later `map` it with a function `Int => Whatever`, or `String => Whatever`, or `Any => Whatever`. This is precisly because of the contravariance of function input explained earlier. That's why your `map` works.

> "what is the point of fixing the type to Nothing if it is to change it
> later?"

I think it's a bit hard to wrap your head around compiler fixing the unknown type to `Nothing` in case of contravariance. When it fixes the unknown type to `Any` in case of covariance, it feels more natural (it can be "Anything"). Because of the duality of covariance and contravariance explained earlier, same reasoning applies for contravariant `Nothing` and covariant `Any`.

Comment: All make sense. Note that I understand Covariance vs Contravariance. Although kudos for the conclusion `Any => Nothing`. Although it helps, it further my original question. I will add an EDIT 2, To explain why ?

Comment: I clarified my question in  EDIT2

Comment: Yeah i am almost there and get it better. First my deduction was wrong in my Edit2. The type indeed does not change when you map, the type of the function to map is actually Nothing => B, to which you can pass Int => B. This is a consequence of the all thing anyway. But before getting to the map there is something else you are saying. Correct me if i am wrong ....

Comment: By making an unspecified Covariant type parameter Nothing, you ensure it Covariability in any circonstance i.e. ```val e: [String, Int] = Left(""")``` works. So I had to see the issue the other way around, than the example I had in my question. 

In the same way, if an unspecified type is Contravariant, by making it Any, we ensure its contravariability in any circonstances .... Your example with which would not compile :) actually examplify that use case for the input parameter.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Method `map` takes a function `Nothing => B1`, where `B1` can be anything, and you supply it with `(e: Int) => e * 4`. This is a perfect example of contravariance in function parameters - you are allowed to pass a function `Int => Int` for the same reason that we were allowed to pass `Food => Apple` or `Any => Apple` in my examples. What didn't compile? I will now add the missing traits, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Ok fully got it. Leads me to one last question, but i will open another one, cause it is connected, but deserves its own thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64969602/clarifying-contravariance-nature-of-the-return-type-of-a-function-as-parameter-a?noredirect=1#comment114861906_64969602

Answer (score 3):

This is a quote from
*Unification of Compile-Time and Runtime Metaprogramming in Scala*
by Eugene Burmako

https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/226166 (p. 95-96)

> During type inference, the typechecker collects constraints on missing
> type arguments from bounds of type parameters, from types of term
> arguments, and even from results of implicit search (type inference
> works together with implicit search because Scala supports an analogue
> of functional dependencies). One can view these constraints as a
> system of inequalities where unknown type arguments are represented as
> type variables and order is imposed by the subtyping relation.
>
> After collecting constraints, the typechecker starts a step-by-step
> process that, on each step, tries to apply a certain transformation to
> inequalities, creating an equivalent, yet supposedly simpler system of
> inequalities. The goal of type inference is to transform the original
> inequalities to equalities that represent a unique solution of the
> original system.
>
> Most of the time, type inference succeeds. In that
> case, missing type arguments are inferred to the types represented by
> the solution.
>
> However, sometimes type inference fails. For example,
> when a type parameter `T` is phantom, i.e. unused in the term parameters
> of the method, its only entry in the system of inequalities will be
> `L <: T <: U`, where `L` and `U` are its lower and upper bound respectively.
> If `L != U`, this inequality does not have a unique solution, and that
> means a failure of type inference.
>
> When type inference fails, i.e.
> when it is unable to take any more transformation steps and its
> working state still contains some inequalities, the typechecker breaks
> the stalemate. It takes all yet uninferred type arguments, i.e. those
> whose variables are still represented by inequalities, and forcibly
> **minimizes** them, i.e. equates them to their lower bounds. This produces
> a result where some type arguments are inferred precisely, and some
> are replaced with seemingly arbitrary types. For instance,
> unconstrained type parameters are inferred to `Nothing`, which is a
> common source of confusion for Scala beginners.

You can learn more about type inference in Scala:

Hubert Plociniczak *Decrypting Local Type Inference* https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/214757

Guillaume Martres *Scala 3, Type Inference and You!* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMvOykNQ4zs

Guillaume Martres *Dotty and types: the story so far* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIQjfCKDR5A

Slides http://guillaume.martres.me/talks/

Aleksander Boruch-Gruszecki *GADTs in Dotty* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VV9lPg3fNl8