# Clarifying contravariance nature of the return type of a function as parameter a function of an outer convariant container

Tags: scala, generics, covariance

In Option we have

```
def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B = this match {
        case None => default
        case Some(a) => a
    }
```

```
def orElse[B >: A](obj: => Option[B]): Option[B] = this match {
        case None => obj
        case _ => this
    }
```

In Either we have:

```
def flatMap[EE >: E, B](f: A => Either[EE, B]): Either[EE, B]
```

I understand what is going and why, a rather extended example could be this

> OrElse( { Option[B]}).map{....} If B is such that  A :> B, then if
> Some(a) you get Some(a).map(f:B => ???) then Kaboom

generally speaking i think i am ok with variance. What i did not see or figure out because that is not what the simple example of co-variance and contravariance explain as use cases, and would like to confirm here:

The return type of a function as parameter is checked for variance position of the outer container.

Typically the example would be

```
Container[+A] {
  def outerfunction[B](value: A): B
}
```

We are then explained, can't do, contra-variance position for A. I will not re-do to full explanation as to why. Let's assume we all understand it.

What is not usually explained is:

```
Container[+A] {
      def outerfunction(f: ??? => A): A
    }
```

It is not just taking a parameter of type A, but also taking any function parameter that return that A. The compiler goes at length to check that too. I wonder if it stops here, or if it is anything that can produce an A, as parameter to a function of the Container.

Comment: Not sure what the question is - WDYM with: _" I wonder if it stops here, or if it is anything that can produce an A, as parameter to a function of the Container."_?

Comment: A function produce an A, but i don't know, another container can be see as a producer of A, e.g. passing a LIST[A] as parameter to a function of Container [+A]

Comment: Granted i could test it straight, i was just thinking maybe i might not think about all the cases.

Comment: Beside i wanted to confirm that, it is indeed because the parameter function Return A, that A, becomes Contravariant.

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand what are you saying. But I will try my best: 1. While it is true that you can think on any covariant type constructor as a producer and as such as a function that returns `A`s, and most of them have a natural operation that works like a function _(and even most of them implement the function trait)_ it doesn't mean that you can always pass an instance of a covariant class where a function is expected on its own, but creating a lambda should be straightforward _(does that makes sense?)_

Comment: _"Besides I wanted to confirm that, it is indeed because the parameter function Return A, that A, becomes Contravariant"_ while having to return an `A` forces the type to be covariant, Usually you should do the opposite rationale, you should think what is the purpose of the class / type constructor you are defining, how should it be used, how should it interact on terms of subtyping. As such, you usually have an intended variance in mind, then you try to implement your methods following that variance, if the compiler complains is because you were to do something unsafe, so you fix it.

Comment: Your comment above this one and in particular "but creating a lambda should be straightforward (does that makes sense?)", means, no for every Container passed as parameter, but yes to a lambda because it is straightforward that it might result in something unsafe

Comment: So lets assume `def foo[A](f: Int => A): A = f(0)` because the stdlib **List** is also a **Function1** from **Int** to **A** you can do this: `foo(List(1, 2, 3))`. Now, lets assume **List** didn't extend **Function1**, as such the previous wouldn't compile, but as I said it would be straight forward to create a lambda like `foo(List(1, 2, 3).apply)` or `foo(i => List(1, 2, 3)(i))` _(which are equivalent)_ - Because all covariant typeconstructor are naturally producers of values, and functions are producers of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is completely correct. To be honest, I am not sure what exactly is the question, but I will assume it's - which places does compiler check in a case such as:

```
trait Container[+A] {
  def outerfunction(f: String => A): A
}
```

And the answer is - all of them.

So when compiler sees `trait Container[+A]`, it will check the body of that `Container` for all occurrences of `A`, to see if they are in:

- parameter position (which brings the contravariant requirement)
- return type position (covariant requirement)
- both (invariant requirement)
- neither (so-called [phantom variance](https://www.benjamin.pizza/posts/2019-01-11-the-fourth-type-of-variance.html)).

In case of `Container[+A]`, it will require that all occurrences of `A` are in covariant position, meaning that it will have a problem with `String => A`.

It's as simple as that. Doesn't matter if it's an "inner function" or an "outer function".

Comment: coming back to this a little. I have a case with another situation that makes me revisit this a little. In your own words, why would the compiler have a problem with `String => A`. From f perspective A is in covariant position, but from the Container perspective, that is a different story. I understand that this is probably obvious, but again just want a confirmation with your own words.

Comment: Exactly what you said. `A` is the return type of function `f`, and return type is a covariant position. But whole function `f` is the parameter of method `outerfunction`, and that's a contravariant position. Note that functions (unlike methods) cannot be parameterized,  so `f` cannot complain anyway. Also note - and this is quite important - that the variance is the quality of the class, not of the parameter. We say "class Container is covariant in its type". If you moved `[+A]` from the class to the method, making it `def outerfunction[A]`, then you wouldn't be able to define variance via +-.

Comment: Cristal clear !!! Thank you for taking the time and the extra tip !!!