# Scala 2 type inference

Tags: scala, type-inference

```scala
def test[T: ClassTag]: T = {
  println(classTag[T])
  null.asInstanceOf[T]
}
val x1: Int = test
val x2: Int = test[Int]
```

prints

```
Nothing
Int
```

I would expect the compiler to guess the `Int` type without the need to provide it explicitly (EDIT: on the right hand side, i.e. make `val x1: Int = test` work).

Is there perhaps a workaround to get rid of the explicit type annotation?

Comment: You are probably expecting wrong things. As your question does not clarify what you were expecting and how Scala is not matching your expectations, you will have to add clear details.

Comment: From what I can see, Scala can perfectly infer the type of `x2` as `Int` in `val x2 = test[Int]` even without explicitly saying `val x2: Int`. What exactly is not working for you ?

Comment: I would expect Scala to infer the type paramter `T == Int` (not `Nothing `) in the line `val x1: Int = test`

Comment: You can get what you expected in Scala3 ^_^，there are many enhance of type inference in Scala3.

Comment: @Eastsun Well, the difference with Scala 3 is now that in Scala 3 `Nothing` doesn't have class tag https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/OAEoGDbmTiafBCrK5KGcmw/3 while in Scala 2 it does https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/OAEoGDbmTiafBCrK5KGcmw/4

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that compiler can't infer `Int` in `val x1: Int = test[???]` because both options:

```
val x1: Int = test[Int] // returns Int
```

and

```
val x1: Int = test[Nothing] // returns Nothing <: Int
```

are valid. So compiler just has to guess what option you meant.

When compiler has a choice it often selects the minimal type out of the options. And currently this is `Nothing`.

[Why Scala Infer the Bottom Type when the type parameter is not specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64966219/why-scala-infer-the-bottom-type-when-the-type-parameter-is-not-specified)

---

In principle, if you'd like to explore the type of left hand side you can make `test` a [macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html). Then it can be even not generic. Making it [whitebox](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/blackbox-whitebox.html#blackbox-and-whitebox-macros) means that it can return a type more precise than declared (`Any`) e.g. `Int`.

```scala
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox // libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
import scala.language.experimental.macros

def test: Any = macro testImpl

def testImpl(c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val T = c.internal.enclosingOwner.typeSignature
  println(s"T=$T")
  q"""
    _root_.scala.Predef.println(_root_.scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[$T])
    null.asInstanceOf[$T]
  """
}
```

```scala
// in a different subproject

val x1: Int = test // prints at runtime: Int

  // scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-debug-lite"
//scalac: T=Int

//scalac: {
//  _root_.scala.Predef.println(_root_.scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[Int]);
//  null.asInstanceOf[Int]
//}
```

Comment: Yeah this one also makes complete sense, I tried implementing a more verbose version of the same exact method like this: `def testImpl[T, U >: T : ClassTag, L <: T : ClassTag]: T = { println(classTag[L]); println(classTag[U]; null.asInstanceOf[T] }`, and then delegating the implementation is `test[T]` method to `testImpl[T, T, T]`. And what I saw is that both upper bound and lower bounds of T are `Nothing`, so it makes sense that `T` is also Nothing!

Comment: I guess at least in Scala2, this problem cannot be solved, it should be handled with alternatives such as `Either` or something. @KamilKloch

Comment: @AminMal Well, I solved it eventually but with macros.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's nothing wrong with type inference here, type inference here means that the compiler should figure out that the `T` type parameter is `Int`, and the returned value from your method expression is an integer, and that's working properly:

```scala
x1: Int = 0 // this is the result of your first line
```

You can also try printing this:

```scala
println(x1.getClass) // int
```

What's not working as expected is implicit resolution for a generic type `"ClassTag[_]"`. The reason it prints `Nothing` is that the compiler found the object `scala.reflect.ClassTag.Nothing : ClassTag[Nothing]` suitable for your case. Now about this new thing, there are loads of content on SO and the internet for why this happens and how to deal with it in different cases.

Here's another piece of code to differentiate `type inference` with `type erasure` in your case:

```scala
def nullAs[T]: T = null.asInstanceOf[T]

val int: Int = nullAs // 0: Int

// type erasure:
case class Container[T](value: T)
implicit val charContainer: Container[Char] = Container('c')

def nullWithContainer[T](implicit container: Container[T]): T = {
  println(container)
  null.asInstanceOf[T]
}

val long: Long = nullWithContainer
// prints Container(c)
// 0L
```

Which means type inference is done correctly, but type erasure has happened, because in runtime, the type of `charContainer` is `Container`, not `Container[Char]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
val x1: Int = test
```

In this line, the `Int` you have given is the type for the value `x1` which would hold the result of the function `test` and as for the `classTag` of `T` the compiler finds no information which is why it returns `Nothing`, in which case its taking  `val x1: Int  = test[Nothing]` so you would always have to mention a Type for `test` else it would print `Nothing`